# mount -a locks up my script if any of many remote drives are offline

Tags: shell-script, mount, fstab, automounting

I've written a backup script which backs up multiple windows servers by mapping those server's hard drives to the linux file system at a particular mount points.

At the beginning of the script, I have this command:
mount -a

The intention of this command, is to make sure that all the remote mounts (specified in the fstab file) are mounted (because if one of the servers have been rebooted, since the last mount,  it would need to remount that server before proceeding).

All of this has been working fine for a month, until today when one of the power supplies went out in one of the windows servers being backed up.

Now, since that server can't be mounted (because it is down), the script won't proceed past the mount -a command.

Ideally, I'd like mount -a to mount if it can, and if it can't proceed to the rest of the script. Instead, it is hanging indefinitely.

How can I keep mount -a from being such a "show-stopper", in the event that one of many server is down? Just because one server is down, doesn't mean I don't want to backup the rest of them

Comment: Consider using a real mult-platform backup solution. Any Windows backup system that does not use VSS, won't be backing everything up.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming these windows file systems are the cifs mount type,

```
mount -a -t nocifs
mount -a -F -t cifs
```

This will mount all non-cifs filesystems, then mount all cifs filesystems in the background and return immediately. The downside, of course, is that it might return before *any* cifs filesystems are mounted, so you may have to wait a few seconds and then check that each filesystem got mounted.

Answer (score 2):

You may need to mount the share with the "soft" option. If a process attempts to connect to the share that is not available it will stop trying after a certain amount of time.

```
soft Make the mount soft. Fail file system calls after a number of seconds.
```

Read more about Soft mount vs Hard mount:

- [What are the advantages/disadvantages of hard versus soft mounts in UNIX?](https://serverfault.com/questions/9499/what-are-the-advantages-disadvantages-of-hard-versus-soft-mounts-in-unix)
- [cifs client timeouts and hard/soft mounts](https://lists.samba.org/archive/samba-technical/2010-December/075029.html)